# Blog Category level Permission

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, blog, categories

I have a problem with a SP 2013 Blog and don't even know if what I want to do is possible.

The thing I want to do is to manage permissions on the category level.

For example:

```
Category A
Category B

Group A (User1, User2)
Group B (User3, User4)
```

User1 and 2 can only add/edit/delete/comment posts in category A. Users 3 and 4 can only add/edit/delete/comment posts in Category B.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your only option is to deploy a custom Item EventReceiver for synchronous operations like Adding, Updating and Deleting. You'd check the field and group memberships and cancel the event if anything is wrong with the combination.

A custom security trimmed control also comes to mind as a to-do item.

Seems too complex to bother actually. Why not aggregate different blogs into a feed instead?